# Setting up linux routing

Tags: linux, networking, routing, route, ip-routing

The system I'm trying to set up has an IP address **172.31.2.1**. Its default gateway is **172.31.254.1**. This works fine, and I can reach anything the gateway allows me to go to (**172.31.0.0/16** + **149.244.178.0/24**).

There is another gateway at **149.244.178.1** which will allow me to reach anything in **149.244.0.0**, and I'm trying to add that to the table so I can access **149.244.64.250**.

This is what my routing table currently looks like:

```
Kernel IP Routing table
Destination    Gateway      Genmask      Flags    Metric    Ref    Use    Iface
172.31.0.0     *            255.255.0.0  U        0         0        0    eth0
169.254.0.0    *            255.255.0.0  U        0         0        0    eth0
default        172.31.254.1 0.0.0.0      UG       0         0        0    eth0
```

**route add 149.244.0.0/16 gw 149.244.178.1** gives the error:

```
route: netmask 0000ffff doesn't make sense with host route.
```

**route add -net 149.244.0.0/16 dev eth0** changes the route table to:

```
Kernel IP Routing table
Destination    Gateway      Genmask      Flags    Metric    Ref    Use    Iface
172.31.0.0     *            255.255.0.0  U        0         0        0    eth0
169.254.0.0    *            255.255.0.0  U        0         0        0    eth0
149.244.0.0    *            255.255.0.0  U        0         0        0    eth0
default        172.31.254.1 0.0.0.0      UG       0         0        0    eth0
```

However, trying to add the gateway still gives me the same error. Sorry if it sounds convoluted, and any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 149.x.x.x host wouldn't be on your local subnet, so your computer would have no way of contacting it. A router between your subnet and that subnet should have both a 149.x and a 172.x address (on two different NICs hopefully), it would route between the two subnets.

Comment: Or to put it a different way.  Your routes always should specify a gateway on the directly attached networks that will be the next hop.

Comment: Ok. I thought that was the case, but was hoping against hope. Oh well.